# How to calculate server resources used by asp.net application

Tags: c#

i had an application hosted on IIS7 window server 2012.
need to know how much resources this application had consumed.

this application has 300+ active user in one time. and i use seprate server for storing session.

Comment: What "resources" are you trying to measure? RAM, CPU, Disk I/O, Network I/O, Database space, Hard drive space? Also what have you tried so far and how has that not been good enough?

Comment: hi .. thanx for the response. i want to calculate RAM , CPU and Network bandwidth used by application.

Comment: Ok, and when you set up [Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8590/An-Introduction-To-Performance-Counters) to mesure those things why did they not give you the info you need. (We expect you to do research and attempt to implement it before coming here)